# VBA Variables are not updated with cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA but want to automate certain forms in my company.
The code i'm trying to write focusses on entering data in a table based on an Input sheet and then copies on cell a few rows down depending on one variable (amount of cable cores).
The first routine copies the data to the table and then calls upon the second routing to copy the data down. The problem that i'm encountering is that my variables are not updated with the info from the cell, they stay 0.

It's probably an easy fix but i can't seem to solve it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Data_input()

'Inputs the values from input to Overview sheet

next_row = ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

ws1.Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("Cable_Number").Value
ws1.Cells(next_row, 3).Value = Range("Equipm_Name").Value
ws1.Cells(next_row, 4).Value = Range("Description").Value
ws1.Cells(next_row, 9).Value = Range("Section").Value
ws1.Cells(next_row, 6).Value = Range("Cable_Number").Value

Application.Run "Module3.Data_Copy"

End Sub
```

```
Sub Data_Copy()

Dim b1 As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim x1 As Long



'set amount of cores in b, b is used to determine amount of copy cycles.
b1 = ws2.Range("Cores").Value

x1 = b1 - 1 'adjusted, because one line is already filled in.


Do Until x1 = 0

'Find the last row with data:

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

'Copies the Cablenumber sleeve until all Cores are done:

ws2.Range("Cable_Number").Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("F" & lr + 1)
x1 = x1 - 1
Loop


Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you assign a value to `x` anywhere?

Comment: No need use Application.Run "Module3.Data_Copy" try this: call Data_Copy (and Data Copy is a Public Function where is out of this module, and Private to call in same module. This code ... Range("Cable_Number").Value it's loose, use Thisworkbook.sheet("namesheet").Range("Cable_Number").Value.

Comment: There is 2 `End With` in your code but no `With`. Your code cannot work at all. Please show a [mcve] of your problem. What is `ws_output` and `Overview`? They are not defined. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variable properly.

Comment: You say *"that my variables are not updated"* **which** variables **exactly** do you speak about and where (which position) in the code?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I copied the wrong version of my code, you are correct about the ''end with''.

Comment: I'm talking about the variable x1, lr and b1. ws1 is the name I've given to the worksheet containing the table were the output is copied to.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding the explicit tag of the worksheet to each cell value that I want to assign to a variable. Sorry for the initial sloppy question. Friday afternoon and frustrated about not being able to fix the code... Thank you for the input.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).